# Unexpected assemblyBinding entries in .config file

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

In my VS2019 C# solution targeting .NET 4.7.1, the projects have "Auto-generate binding redirects" checked, and contain NuGet repository.config files. Some of the package.config files contain this entry:

`<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net471" />`

and that is the version of the NuGet package that is installed.

After building, these lines got added to the .config file:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.3" newVersion="4.1.1.3" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Those lines are not present in the corresponding app.config file. So why does VS2019 think this section is needed in the .config? Even if it was needed, shouldn't the entry be:

```
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.4.0" newVersion="4.3.4.0" />
```

There are other identical entries in the package.config files that didn't warrant coverage in the .config file, so it doesn't seem to be due to some "if present in multiple package.config files" rule.

Comment: `bindingRedirect` can be added by other package where `System.Net.Http` is a transitive dependency

Comment: Since I installed version 4.3.4, why would VS2019 be telling other assemblies to look for 4.1.1.3?